# Is Kamadeva (Manmatha) still alive or dead?

Tags: gods, shiva-purana, kamadeva

I heard a story about *Kamadeva*, here it is:

While *Lord Shiva* was doing deep meditation, *Kamadeva* disturbs him by inducing love and desire into *Shiva*, which caused disturbance to *Shiva* and made *Shiva* angry. Because of which *Shiva* opened his third eye and burned *Kamadeva* and turned him into ashes. But by the request of *Devi Rati*, *Shiva* resurrects *Kamadeva* only for *Rati* such that she only can see.

Is he really dead for others? If he died, then how come humans still get feelings of love and desire with out the existence of *Kamadeva*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Kamadeva is alive now with body but he lived without body till his birth as Krishna's son Pradyumna. He regained his body after taking birth as Pradyumna during 28th Dwapara Yuga of this Manvantara. Kamadeva as Pradyumna married Rati
after killing Shambasura.

This is [mentioned](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/siva-mahapurana/vol-i/chapter-114/topic-1) by Lord Shiva Himself in Chapter 19 Rudra Samhita (Parvati Khanda) of Shiva Mahapurana.

> शिव उवाच 
>  देवाश्च ऋषयः सर्वे मद्वचः शृणुतादरात्। मत्कोपेन च
> यञ्जातं तत्तथा नान्यथा भवेत्॥३७॥
>
> Siva said, “O Gods and Rsis, you listen to my words carefully with
> respect. Whatever has happened out of my fury cannot be altered.
>
> **अनङ्गस्तावदेव स्यात्कामो रतिपतिः प्रभुः। यावच्चावतरेत्कृष्णो धरण्यां रुक्मिणीपतिः।।३८।।**
>
> **The lord Kamadeva shall remain, without a body till lord Krsna- the husband of Rukmini, incarnates on earth.**
>
> द्वारकायां यदा स्थित्वा पुत्रानुत्पादयिष्यति। तदा कृष्णस्तु
> रुक्मिण्यां काममुत्पादयिष्यति॥३९॥
>
> Living in Dvaraka, when Krsna, shall produce the sons, then Rukmini
> would give birth to Kama.
>
> प्रद्युम्नं नाम तस्यैव भविष्यति न संशयः। जातमात्रं तु तं पुत्रं शम्बरः
> स हरिष्यति॥४० ।।
>
> He would surely be known by the name of Pradyumna. Soon after his
> birth that son would be kidnapped by Sambhasura,
>
> हृत्वा प्रास्य समुद्रे तं शम्बरो दानवोत्तमः। मृतं ज्ञात्वा वृथा मूढो
> नगरं स्वं गमिष्यति।।४१।।
>
> Šarinbhāra, the best of Danavas, after kidnapping Krsna's son and
> foolishly taking him to be dead, would throw him in the ocean and then
> return to his city.
>
> तावच्च नगरं तस्य रते! स्थेयं यथासुखम्। तत्रैव स्वपतेः प्राप्तिः
> प्रद्युम्नस्य भविष्यति।।४२।।
>
> O Rati, you shall stay in the city till then, where you will get back
> your husband.
>
> **तत्र कामो मिलित्वा तं हत्वा शम्बरमाहवे। भविष्यति सुखी देवाः प्रद्युम्नाख्यः स्वकामिनीम्।**
>
> **Then Kámadeva, killing Sambhasura in the battle, shall achieve his wife Rati and get delighted. The gods too will rejoice.**
>
> तदीयं चैव यद्द्रव्यं नीत्वा स नगरं पुनः। गमिष्यति तया सार्द्धं देवाः
> सत्यं वचो मम।।४४।।
>
> O Gods, carrying the riches of Sambhasura and his wife, Pradyumna
> shall return to his abode, My words are true.”

Comment: This should be the marked answer

Answer (score 7):

According to *Shiva Puran*

> *Lord Shiva* told the deities that *Kamadeva* would take birth as the son of *Krishna* and *Rukmini* in the era of dwapar. A demon by the name of Shambar would throw him off in the sea. He would kill that demon and marry *Rati*, who too would be living in a city near the sea.
>
> But the deities were not satisfied. They requested *Lord Shiva* to help *Rati* to unite with her husband. *Lord Shiva* then told them that *Kamadeva* would become his Gana, but he also warned them against revealing this fact to anybody. Rati then went to the city where the demon Shambar was expected to appear in the era of dwapar. The deities too went back to the heaven.

This clearifies that kamadeva is still alive and is now the gana of Shiva.

**End Note :** *Kamadeva is still alive, doing the same job, but under different leader.*

Comment: what gana means ?

Comment: @hanu, gana were attendants of shiva, which lived with him. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gana

Comment: Give Reference which chapter which book of Shiva Purana

Comment: @AnuragSingh, I don't think I can provide you with those details, as Hinduism is a huge composite of books. It would be very hard to get into smaller details many of things we as modern Hindus learn are from our ancestors or scattered resources.

Comment: No, I just asked from Shiva Purana and not from rest Purana.