# Does one eye of Lord Shiva always remain open?

Tags: shiva

The three eye God is famous for his penance most. At time of penance his eyes remain close and time duration of his penance is also extremely long. But I heard an incident in which Parvati asked Shiva to close his eyes. Then whole universe turned dark. Even Sun's light turned off. Then Shiva did open his third eye and all universe become light up again. He didn't open his two eyes because Paravati asked to close them but didn't say anything about third eye so Shiva opened that eye.

Then Parvati was also suprised by seeing that Shiva opened his third eye. She asked to open his eyes again. Then he closed his third eye only after open his primary two eyes.

Parvati asked to Shiva, Why you open your third eye? What was need to open it? Then Shiva told, It can never happen when I close my all eyes from this world. I have to always keep one eye open to see the world. I can't turn my eye off from this world. If in any case I have to close my eyes for some reason then its becomes mandatory to open my third eye.

If this is really true then what about time of penance? On penance he sure remains close his two eyes but is third eye remain open when Shiva does penance? Do scriptures says something about his third eye? Is it true Shiva keep one eye open even in penance? Or penance is exception?

Comment: What penance you are talking about? After separation from Sati? Exact story  of Parvati devi closing eyes can be found [in this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15217/3500).

Comment: @thedestroyer I am not talking about any particular special penance. I mean whenever Shiva do penance then one eye remain open? And I am talking about fourth incident in mentioned question.

Comment: If i understand your question correctly, you are asking "why world doesn't become black when Shiva stays in yogic padmanasana posture with closed eyes "? (this is how Shiva is generally depicted in many pictures)

Comment: @thedestroyer Yes, kind of this is what I am asking. But I was asking in different way. I means, after hearing this story I came to know that Shiva keep one eye open always. So question can be consider in two ways. First way (in which I asked) is, Do Shiva keep one eye open in penance also? Or other way (as you figured) is, why world don't turn dark when he keep all eyes close during penance? Whether we ask in any way but answer will remain say. So you can consider my question in any way since answer will be same :)

Comment: @TheDestroyer and rishabh- in the yogic posture, lord's eyes are not fully closed. It is a yogic mudra that requires focusing the sight on edge of the nose.

Comment: @moonstar2001 It depends, focus is done either on the tip of the nose or on Ajna Chakra.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria When i say edge of nose i meant between the brows. It is never at the tip of the nose afaik.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the question as well. I assume you are talking about  meditation or yogic posture. Well, I think Lord Shiva never close his eyes.

Most of the time, when people think of meditation, they think of closing their eyes and after some time they create random imaginations which keeps on shifting from one position to another. Meditation means not to be affected by outside world. It does not want us to be blind. When you close your eyes then you will probably start visualizing. This visualization looks very nice (full of bright colors). This visualization is nothing but an imagination. You are making yourself blind and getting into a state of hibernation (sleep).

Meditation or penance is done by opened eyes or half-opened eyes. You should meditate by becoming fully awake. To do this, you half-close your eyes and look at the tip of your nose. After that you don't move your eyes, your eye balls e.t.c.

Even In **Bhagavat Gita** Lord Krishna Says In Chapter VI Verse 12-13,

**तत्रैकाग्रं मन: कृत्वा यतचित्तेन्द्रियक्रिय: |
उपविश्यासने युञ्ज्याद्योगमात्मविशुद्धये || 12||
समं कायशिरोग्रीवं धारयन्नचलं स्थिर: |
सम्प्रेक्ष्य नासिकाग्रं स्वं दिशश्चानवलोकयन् || 13||**

Seated firmly on it, the yogi should strive to purify the mind by focusing it in meditation with one pointed concentration, controlling all thoughts and activities. He must hold the body, neck, and head firmly in a straight line, and gaze at the tip of the nose, without allowing the eyes to wander.

http://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/6/verse/12-13

Similar interpretation from other site,

**Sloka
6.13

Let him firmly hold his body, head and neck erect and still, (with the eye-balls fixed, as if) gazing at the tip of his nose, and not looking around. 13**

Comment: You are saying opposite of Bhagwat Geeta. Lord Krishna said in BG that to do meditation one need to close his eyes. Because if we keep our eyes open then by seeing views of world we will surely get distract. Closing your eyes helps to avoid distraction.

Comment: I am not saying  opposite, I am actually telling the best way. You can of course close your eyes, but the way to do it is by concentrating on the tip of your nose or by the looking at the center area (between the eyebrows), and to do this you will have to slightly open your eyes. Please read the sloka above.